# Disable reloading of ZIP and phone in checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout

**Magento 2.4.4**

The checkout does a reload after every character I enter in the ZIP or phone field. I tried finding a setting to disable this, but could not find any. Is there a way to stop reloading after every keyup?

Thanks